# Slow performance of ST_AsMVT for huge PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, performance, tile-server, mapbox-vector-tile, pg-tileserv

I am fetching MVT tiles from a PostGIS database in combination with `pg_tileserve`.
When fetching tiles from a fairly small dataset (some 10000 features) this works quite performant.
But when fetching features from a huge database like 10000000+ features (e.g. Linestrings) this is getting very slow although when viewing the map on a higher (18) zoomlevel. When I guess the retrieved amount of data is the same.

This seems somehow unexpected to me, as I would expect PostGIS to efficiently retrieve features as it is a geospatial database.

Can someone tell me if there are any recommendations for configuring `pg_tileserve` with PostGIS to improve performance. Or is this in the end a bad combination?

Calls towards PostGIS:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public.roadlinesmy_table', 4096, 'geometry') FROM (
        SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
                ST_Transform(ST_Force2D(t."geometry"), 3857),
                bounds.geom_clip,
                4096,
                256
          ) AS "geometry"

          , "PRPASSAGE", "HOUSE_N", "Dest", "A", "S", "TUNNEL_NAME", "ROAD_NUMBER", "ROAD_NAME", "P", "I", "F", "m", "id", "HR", "G", "RO", "SPEED", "B", "g", "R", "road", "ADMIN", "FUNCT", "WARN", "NUM"

        FROM "public"."roadlinesmy_table" t, (
                SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(1.0273136601527669e+06, 6.2421534778806195e+06, 1.0370975997732691e+06, 6.251937417501122e+06, 3857)  AS geom_clip,
                                ST_MakeEnvelope(1.0267021639264855e+06, 6.241541981654339e+06, 1.0377090959995505e+06, 6.252548913727403e+06, 3857) AS geom_query
                ) bounds
        WHERE ST_Intersects(t."geometry",
                                                ST_Transform(bounds.geom_query, 3857))

        LIMIT 50000
) mvtgeom
```

Comment: It will always take time to read and process 10000000+ features - do you have indexes on your table. Please provide the `explain` results for the query

Comment: what are explain results? do I have to configure postgis to use indexes?

Comment: `explain` is a SQL command that you prepend to your query to explain where the time is going. And yes of course you need to create indexes it is not magic

Comment: Low zoom levels are the slowest of all. At zoom level 0 one tile covers the whole world, so every feature from the database. Filter with SQL what data are relevant to include into the low zoom levels, and index the fields that are needed for filtering. I see that you do have LIMIT 50000, but  using limit without indexes is sometimes slow.

Comment: I now created an index via:
"CREATE INDEX spatial_index ON "+dbTableName+" USING GIST ( geometry );";
and afterwards
VACUUM ANALYZE;
is this correct or are there more optimizations available?

Comment: Hm for one table this seemed to have increased performance drastically but now after applying CREATE INDEX call to the next table performance is worse again. Is my command incorrect?

Comment: @IanTurton Is GIST the best option for indexing a huge set of LineString geometries and retrieving them via scrolling in a browser using BoundingBoxes?

Comment: please [edit] your question with the `explain` results and the indexes you have added - we really can't help with out that information